# Categorizing data by partial attribute

Tags: qgis, classification, expression

In QGIS 3.4 I'm trying to categorize a column in my attribute table which contains a code, of which I only need the (highest) number (which implies a gradation). This probably means I need an expression to filter out the letters.

The code looks, for example, like this:

```
BA1ZA1PU3
```

The output in this example should be number 3.

To make it a bit more difficult, numbers higher than 6 shouldn't be taken in consideration and number 6 is less weighty than number 1.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in your field, the number in the code varies from 1 to 9 (only one digit), you can use the following code :

```sql
CASE
  WHEN to_int(right("my_code_field", 1)) = 6 THEN 0
  WHEN to_int(right("my_code_field", 1)) > 6 THEN Null
  ELSE to_int(right("my_code_field", 1))
END
```

For explanations, I use the conditional function `CASE WHEN condition THEN result ELSE else_result END` with the `right` function which extract the 1 character from the right of the code, and convert it into integer with `to_int`.

Case when the value equals 6, then return `0` as value, when the value is higher than 6 return `Null`, else return the value.

---

#### EDIT

And here is the solution, no matter the length of the number :

```sql
with_variable(
   'code',
   to_int(substr("my_code_field", regexp_match("my_code_field", '[0-9]*$'))),
  CASE
    WHEN @code = 6 THEN 0
    WHEN @code > 6 THEN Null
    ELSE @code
  END
)
```